# Installing Graphics Drivers on Dell XPS 17

Tags: 13.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xps

Can anyone give me specific information on WHAT am I supposed to do to install the graphics cards drivers on my laptop?

I have a Dell XPS 17 which comes with Intel HD Graphics as integrated card and Nvidia GT 525M as dedicated card.

Ubuntu only recognizes Intel's, and recognizes it as Intel Sandybridge Mobile, even after installing `mesa-utils`.

I tried everything I could in the past: tried installing `bumblebee`, `nvidia-current`, and even tried downloading the graphics card drivers directly from Nvidia's website. It just won't work; I end up corrupting it, and can't revert the changes. The screen gets stuck in a resolution smaller than my laptop's default one (which is Full HD), not to count the times when Unity just won't open.

This made me format my laptop about four times, and I don't want to mess up again this time.

I'd be glad if anyone could give me proper directions or show me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I have the XPS 17 too, although perhaps it's a later model (L702X?) as I seem to recall my graphics card is a 555M. I've got bumblebee installed and it works brilliantly. So care you saying that you install bumblebee correctly, then restart, and you get bumped to the lower resolution?

Comment: Yes, yours is a later version, it's an L502X. I tried installing bumblebee about two times. Every time, the same error. The first time, I was able to make Unity work again by removing bumblebee, but then the resolution problem was irreversible (at least for my knowledge).

Comment: Did you follow the instructions (here)[https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation]? I installed it a year and a half ago, and did record the details, but I suspect they might have changed since.

Comment: Also, it might be worth contacting the Bumblebee devs, as I've found them very responsive and helpful in the past.

Comment: I'll try to follow the instructions. They're different from what I've tried few months ago too. Then I'll post the result.

Comment: I can't believe this, but it actually worked... I don't know the exact reason, but it's working pretty well. Thank you.

Comment: Brilliant! I'm so glad it worked for you. These kinds of problems can be so frustrating to troubleshoot. I guess I implied it earlier, but I think that bumblebee is the only real way of leveraging your computers GPU properly. I don't feel like I've done too much, but I'll write up a brief answer so you can accept it and hence close this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have the newer version of the XPS 17 (L702X). I installed bumblebee about a year and a half ago and it works very well.

You can try and follow the instructions on the [Ubuntu wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) to install Bumblebee again.